# PHP refreshing a temporary form while a process is running

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a simple E-mail done.  I want this email form to run during a process.   The user will submit a query.  He will have to wait a short time to get the results.  During this short time I want the screen to show my E mail form and constantly refresh every 5 seconds, when the process is finished and the results are ready I want the form to leave, and the script to continue to the results page created.

I was thinking javascript?

```
     function timeRefresh(timeoutperiod){
     setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
```

Any suggestions Please?

Comment: Does your own idea do what you want it to?

Comment: you could use XmlHttpRequest to sent a small `ping` to the server to check for the update. this is how most chat systems work. the technique is called "long polling" if you want to run a search for it.

Comment: how would you query the state of the process in php? have u already written that and is that an client side only problem? please specify further what you need or what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform the query using AJAX request

and when the request sent show a light box you can use this one I like it

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

after the response comes back from the server you check if the textfield is empty or not if its empty close the light box else let the user finish the form and close it

if you need code just leave a comment

---

```
// show light box 
$.ajax({

                  url: 'QueryFile.php',
                  type:'post',
                  data:{variable:value,},
                  dataType:'html',
                  success: function(data) {
                     //close modal box 
                  },
                 error:function(error)
                 {
                     console.log(error); 
                    alert("Sorry there was an error while performing your query ");  
                 }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i need.  I am sorry I am teaching myslef Php and am not familiar with AJAX request. I have read something about it, however still not fully sure how to do this.

Comment: I suggest you read up on XmlHttpRequest (this is the method used to pass the data to the server from your static page). Know at least what is going on behind the scenes when you are using $ magic. or alternatives include things like http://rlemon.github.com/Little-XHR there are many small libs out there with many options. at least you can learn a few things by reading them.